# R package AzureStor: how do you download files with hierarchical namespace enabled?

Tags: r, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the AzureStor package to download event notifications from an Azure blob.

I managed to successfully execute the download for one file by using a specific file endpoint:

```
DownloadURL1 <- "https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/callrecords/evh-callrecords/callrecords/0/2022/07/28/19/05/09.avro"
DestinationFolder <- "./home/Shared/AVRO_FILES/09.avro"

Azure_Token <- AzureRMR::get_azure_token(resource = "https://storage.azure.com/", tenant = TenantID, app = AppID, password = Secret)
        
download_from_url(DownloadURL1, key = StorageAccessKey, DestinationFolder, overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

However, I would need to download all the notification files from the blob and I have hierarchical namespace enabled in Azure with this structure:

```
 {Namespace}/{EventHub}/{PartitionId}/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Minute}/{Second}
```

Is there a way to handle these hierarchical name spaces? I've seen a "directory_depth" argument but I can't figure out how to use it...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that ***`Blob storage does not actually  have true directories`*** and that seems like it includes folders and subfolders but that is simply a naming convention, using filenames containing a separator character (’/’) to mimic a directory but they have just a flat structure.

> But in **azure data lake  basically hierarchical namespace organizes the
> objects or files into a hierarchy of directories** . So to actually download files with directories and
> subdirectories you can check with adls gen2 filesystem rather than
> just blob. [adls :***`Operations on an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2`***
> filesystem in AzureStor: (rdrr.io)](https://rdrr.io/cran/AzureStor/man/adls.html)

- In case of blob please check with the `multidownload_blob` which is
  function for downloading multiple files at once by using AzureRMR to
  parallely transfer  many small files.
- Both src and dest can be vectors and the src  can be a wildcard
  pattern indicating to one or more files. If `recursive is true` here,
  the file transfer will replicate the source directory structure  and
  to recursively transfer files in subdirectories at the destination.

> *Format:*
>
> multidownload_blob(container, src, dest, recursive = FALSE,
> blocksize = 2^24, overwrite = FALSE, lease = NULL, check_md5 = FALSE,
> use_azcopy = FALSE, max_concurrent_transfers = 10)

*example:* snippet from below reference

```
cont <- blob_container("https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer", key="access_key")
multidownload_blob(cont, "jan*.*", "/data/january")
```

Reference: [AzureStor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureStor/AzureStor.pdf)

[**use_azcopy**](https://rdrr.io/cran/AzureStor/man/azcopy.html) can be used for [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-download#download-specific-blobs) utility from Microsoft , rather than doing it in native R code which can useful if you want have benefit of logging and recovery features and for transferring a very large number of small files. To enable , set the `use_azcopy argument to TRUE`.

> **NOTE:** • It only supports SAS and AAD (OAuth) token as authentication methods. AzCopy also expects a single filename or
> wildcard spec as its source/destination argument, not a vector of
> filenames or a connection.

For a service SAS, the depth of the directory, starts at 0 for the root and the account has a hierarchical namespace enabled which lets you scan the directories structure as deep as you want i.e.; number of directories beneath the root folder ex: 8 or 5. This is required if `resource_type="d"`  *d to indicate the depth of the directory*

*sample:*

> ```
> get_service_sas(account, resource, key, service,
> start = NULL, expiry = NULL, permissions = "rl",
> resource_type = “d”, ip = NULL, protocol = NULL, policy = NULL,
> snapshot_time = NULL, directory_depth = 6,
> auth_api_version = getOption("azure_storage_api_version"), ...)
> ```
>
> ***`snapshot ,version`*** should be datetime strings, in the format `"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS.SSSSSSSZ"`. If they are not mentioned,
> the base blob is downloaded.

```
# service SAS for a directory get_service_sas(endp, "containername/dirname")
```

*ex:*

```
endp <- storage_endpoint("https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net", sas="mysas")
cont <- storage_container(endp, "mycontainer")

multidownload_blob(cont, src, dest, recursive = TRUE, ....,
  use_azcopy =TRUE, max_concurrent_transfers = 10)
```

**Reference**: [Operations on a blob container or blob](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/AzureStor/html/blob.html)

Comment: Wow, thank you for the extensive explanation! I will check out the options and see what works best! THANK YOU!